# how to upload file to ftp related path quickly in notepad++?

Tags: ftp, notepad++

for example:
my local file path is

```
d:/www/zencart/includes/pages/checkout_shipping/header_php.php
```

ftp file path is

```
./htdocs/includes/pages/checkout_shipping/header_php.php
```

when I modify my file in my pc , I want to update the file in my ftp the same with my local file , how to do the job quickly? not to use ftp software to find the relatived path in ftp and then upload file ,this method is too slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the newest version of Notepad++ installed with all standard add-ons there is a built-in mini-FTP client. You can find it in `Plugins > NppFTP`

The second option is to add network location in Windows Explorer and save it there as you'd save it on your local computer.

Comment: thank you very much , but npp upload the file at once when I modify my file and save , but I want it upload file whenever I want ,not the time I save it . how to set?